# python itertools.permutations combinations

Tags: python

I have this variable: `message = "Hello World"`
and I built a function that shuffles it:

```
def encrypt3(message,key):
    random.seed(key)
    l = range(len(message))
    random.shuffle(l)
    return "".join([message[x] for x in l])
```

This function just suffle the message so it could look like this for example "Hrl llWodeo"

Now if I want to convert it to the message again using itertools.permutations, how can I do it?
When I tried this : `print [x for x in itertools.permutations(shuffledMsg)]`
the program closed with error because its has to many posibilities.

Comment: You're losing information so this is not encryption.

Comment: It's not losing information, since he's using a known seed.

Comment: Even if you could try all permutations of the cypher text, how will you know that you've successfully decrypted it?

Comment: If you want to convert the message again, you should be checking how shuffle uses the random float to shuffle and do the reverse operation, based on the random seed you used.

Comment: I want to restore the encrypted message when the seed is given, I ask if it is possible

Comment: Why are you designing your own encryption algorithm?

Comment: just for practice :), check new things in python

Comment: If you want to practice cryptography algorithms implementation, there are better ways to combine key to text than the way you're doing. Python random.shuffle isn't an easily reversible operation. You'd be better by generating a stream of random chars based on your random seed and XOR'ing them with the clear text. Doing the same with the cipher text will give you the clear text back.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this too but I want to know if my encryption function is reversible?

Comment: you should define term "reversible" first

Comment: Can I restore the message I incrypted using the function above?

Comment: I don't think that there's any guarantee that `random.shuffle` will be the same function among different implementations of Python. What is reversible on your computer may not be reversible on another, so it is a bad idea to rely on `random.shuffle`. Instead, you could write your own `shuffle` which you know will function exactly the same depending on the seed its given.

Comment: So there is no way to decrypt the message? or using itertools.permutations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of course "unshuffable" so long as you know the original seed, since we can simply re-run it to find out where each character is shifting to.

```
import random

def encrypt3(message,key):
    random.seed(key)
    l = range(len(message))
    random.shuffle(l)
    return "".join([message[x] for x in l])


key = 'bob'
message = 'Hello World!'

print(encrypt3(message, key))


def unshuffle(message, key):
    random.seed(key)
    new_list = list(range(len(message)))
    old_list = [None] * len(new_list)

    random.shuffle(new_list)

    for i, old_i in enumerate(new_list):
        old_list[old_i] = message[i]

    return ''.join(old_list)


print(unshuffle(encrypt3(message, key), key))
```